# "Could not load" error whenever I click a work item

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have recently installed Team Explorer on one of my machines that has Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed. But know whenever I click a work item or trying to open a team query I get the following error:

**Could not load type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeDeniedOrNotExistException' from assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'**

I even repaired the installation of Team Explorer 2008 but it does not solve my problem.
Does anybody know how can I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read a blog post somewhere recently that stated that you had to install Team Explorer before SP1, or else you would have to re-install SP1 again after installing Team Explorer.

Found [the link to the blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/kristol/archive/2009/05/04/installing-the-visual-studio-2008-development-stack-in-the-right-order.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This almost always occurs because you have a mismatch between versions of Visual Studio RTM and SP1 binaries.  I've found the following works for me.

1. Uninstall Team Explorer
2. Repair Visual Studio Install
3. Install Team Explorer (from the web)

Answer (score 1):

1 - download [Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en)

2 - open it by any program which can open .iso
3 - go to "Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\"
4 - copy all assemmblies which name begin with "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking" to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\"

I solve this problem by this way.
Hope it helps you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling vs2008 sp1 fixed this issue for me